# How might I move AngularJS Routes into separate file

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was curious if anybody was familiar with separating routes from the main app config function. My route list is getting quite large and I wanted to move them into a separate file and load them into the main config. I have seen this done before but I cannot remember or find where I saw it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can (and should !) use AngularJS modules to separate your application into modules.

Then, each module can define its own routes (with its own `.config`).
Then, in your main module (usually "app"), you just need to require them as dependencies and you're set to go.

```
angular.module('blog', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    ...
  }];

angular.module('app', ['blog', 'user']);
```

Then you can have each module in its own file.

Comment: you actually left the route definition in the main file though. I'm not faulting your answer, its basically correct and maybe the op change the question along the way. But the question as it stands now is not really answered by this post (see pixelbits' answer for that)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Each module's config block sets up its routes.

Comment: he asked how to separate roues from the module (ie, a different file), not how to separate app functionality into separate modules. Like I said I'm not faulting your response at all, except that it answers a different question.

Comment: It still answers the question. One module per file. Updated.

Answer (score 7):

You can put your config function in a separate file easily:

App-config.js

```
   angular.module('app').config(function(...){...});
```

Just make sure you include the module definition before you include App-config.js.

App-module.js

```
  angular.module('app',[...]).controller(...).etc
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to set up config file separately. There are few other ways to set this up, and I played around with those structure for config; this seems to work for me the best. Enjoy!

---> myApp.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
           <script src="lib/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           <script src="js/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           ...
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

             <!-- /* Using ng-view with routeProvider to render page templates */ -->
            <div data-ng-view></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

----> app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {     
    $routeProvider.when('/page1', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/page1.html',
        controller : 'page1Controller'  
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/page2', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/page2.html',
        controller : 'page2Controller'  
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/images', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/page3.html',
        controller : 'page3Controller'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/page1'});
}]);
```

--->controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myModules'])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  ...
})

.controller('page1', function($scope) {
  ...
})

.controller('page2', function($scope) {
  ...
})

.controller('page3', function($scope) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: that's alright. I'm still using this structure and now it's much more advanced and matured. This structure is currently used in production for well known companies global, just saying.