# AngularJS splitting routes results in module is not available

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-routing

I'm using AngularJS 1.3 on a large single page app and I'm trying to split up my routes file.

I'm following the advice from the following question and have run into problems finding my new module
[How might I move AngularJS Routes into separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251345/how-might-i-move-angularjs-routes-into-separate-file)

My routes-work-desc.js.coffee is

```
angular
  .module('workDesc')
  .config ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

    $stateProvider
      .state "work_descs",
        parent: "default"
        url: "/work_descs"
        views:
          "":
            controller: "WorkDescsController"
            templateUrl: "/assets/work_descs/index.html.erb"
]
```

My routes.js.coffee file is

```
angular
  .module('paisApp', ['workDesc'])
  .config ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise("/")

    $stateProvider
      .state "default",
        abstract: true            # Parent route/template
        views:
          "":
            controller: "ApplicationController"
            templateUrl: "/assets/layouts/default.html.erb"
]
```

The error I get is

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'workDesc' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/nomod?p0=workDesc
```

Comment: Please check if you have initialized the module  .module('workDesc') somwhere by the help of  .module('workDesc', [])

Comment: angular.module(string) is a getter; angular.module(string, array) is a setter. You need to call the setter to initialize the module before you can use the getter to get it.